# Laravel - How to add where statement within related table and parent table at the same time?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, models, relationships

I have two tables: **members** (userdata, email, etc) and **users** (username, password, etc). All users are members but not all members are users. I defined the relationship in laravel:

Member.php

```
public function user() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User');
}
```

Now I want to be able to retrieve a member's data either by email or by username (if it exists) without using `join()`. Basically:

```
where('email','=','blah123')->orWhere('username','=','blah123')
```

I want the relationships returned in their own arrays like:

```
{
    firstname: blah,
    email: blah@blah.com,
    user: [
        username: blah123
    ]
}
```

And when I use `join()` it returns a flat array which is not ideal:

```
{
    firstname: blah,
    email: blah@blah.com,
    username: blah123
}
```

How would I go about it?

Comment: what about u make a custom response

Comment: would you like to share your database tables?

Comment: You are complicating your life "*members (userdata, email, etc) and users (username, password, etc)*"; `email` should be in same table as `password` & `username`. Besides that read the documentation to get everything you need to solve your issue https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
where('email','=','blah123')->orWhereHas('user', function($query) { 
    $query->where('username','=','blah123');
})->with('user')
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem your looking for this kind of solution :-

```
User::with('user')->where('email','=','blah123')->orWhere('username','=','blah123')->first();
```

You can use **with()** keyword for getting relationship data. Hope it helps!

Reference :- https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I get an error message saying the column was not found.

Comment: check your column exist in database or not that you have used in where condition